# Salto de linea entre PHP y HTML

Tags: laravel

Veran, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    $limite=100;
    if(strlen($juego->desarrollo)>$limite)
        $d=substr($juego->desarrollo,0,$limite)."\r\n(Seguir Leyendo)";
    else
        $d=$juego->desarrollo;
?>
<hr>
<span style="background-color:#ffcb83; float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$d}}</span>
```

Esto pretende que se muestre una variable, pero si es muy larga, la recorte, haga un salto de línea y muestre un aviso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

{{$d}}

Pero el salto de línea no se produce.
¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: Prueba con "<br> (Seguir Leyendo)"

Comment: @WalterCordova Así he hecho, pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: Que raro, eso debería funcionar, como en [este ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVFHJU9IRIWW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que la variable $d no es reconocida por html.

debes de incluir la etiqueta html dentro del cuerpo de php.

seria mas o menos asi.

[image: Ejemplo]